# SwiftUI macOS search suggestion incorrected dark mode - don't follow the app preferredColorScheme

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, searchable

I have my system set to Dark Mode, but the app is light mode only, which works fine, having the main content view

.preferredColorScheme(.light)

however the search suggestions doesn't respect that

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigation) {
                Button(action: {
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                })
                Button(action: {
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                })
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar) {
            Text("Font family A").searchCompletion("Hello")
            Text("Font family B").searchCompletion("HelloX")
        }
    }
    .windowToolbarStyle(.unified(showsTitle: false))
    
}
```

[image]

How to make the search suggestion follow the `preferredColorScheme`

Comment: Well formally it is correct, because preferredColorScheme affects only current presentation, suggestions menu is different presentation... the bug is that it is not possible to set preferredColorScheme for suggestions.

Comment: there must be however a way to this for applications that have a fixed color scheme

Comment: If you need that application wide then it can be done in Info.plist. See corresponding section in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app.

Comment: the .info plist didn't worked for me, maybe it is not supported anymore, but found a leading reference to NSApp.appearance

Answer (score 0):

```
NSApp.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
```

did work

reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
        .onAppear(perform: {
            NSApp.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
        }
```